# Running a command in terminal after youtube-dl has finished

Tags: command-line, youtube-dl

As written in the title, I would like to run a command ONLY after the previous command 'youtube-dl' has finished and closes. I am not running this command on bash just on the ubuntu terminal.

I would like to run this command:

```
Youtube-dl -o output.file link ; sleep 4 ; mv output* /to-directory
```

Command 1 can run from 5 seconds to xx minute and if I state just sleep for 4 seconds it may not take enough time to run the command 2 when command 1 has finished and closed regardless of the result. I could use sleep 4 for indefinite timelapse but it would really hampers my speed of executing commands altogether.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, it should be enough to write these commands next to each other with space between them. "command1 command2"

Comment: unfortunately it is not.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, even && does not work properly, because if I run a command that returns an output result file, with &&, command 2 starts right after and cannot find the output file

Comment: So what is the problem? `man bash` says:`Commands separated by a ; are executed sequentially; the shell  waits for  each  command to terminate in turn.` Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: You haven't given your OS/release details, but if I use `mousepad ; sleep 2 ; echo 'hi'` the echo doesn't occur till 2 seconds after I exit mousepad.

Comment: If i run youtube-dl -o output link ; sleep 4: mv output. I cant do it since the output file can be generated between 5 seconds to several minutes

Comment: youtube-dl forks to the background. This is why this construct does not work. It really depends on the command on what happens, so you may want to make your question more specific.

Comment: I figured it it happened something like that, in that case how would I do that?

Comment: If you know which file youtiube-dl writes to, you can use `inotifywait` on a "close" event on that file. Harder to do if of course if youtube-dl writes to some temp file and renames it when done.

Comment: [Edit] your question to include the command you are actually running.

Comment: Your example is somewhat silly, instead of mv'ing just output to target folder to begin with. That being said && works fine here both with dash files and the already muxed file that every vid has.

Comment: This is just a simple example to let the reader understand what problem I am facing. As Ubuntu noob user whenever I face a problem I'd like to find a solution rather than just workaround to understand better since from little knowledge got every now and then I can accumulate some more understanding. That being said, I would like to know how to execute commands on outoupt file of youtube-dl since this command runs in background.

Comment: The pattern `output*` is expanded when the command line is parsed, before any command is run. It can not match output files that do not exist yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Youtube-dl -o output.file link && sleep 4 && mv output* /to-directory`
or even better:
`Youtube-dl -o /to-directory/output.file link` as you would not have to move anything later on.

If youtube-dl indeed runs in background and is set to exit after downloading,
You can use:

```
youtube-dl -o output.file link; while :;do sleep 1; [[ $(ps -C youtube-dl -o pid=) ]] || break;done; mv output.* /to-directory/
```

**Explanation**
`while :;` - an infinite loop meant to wait for youtube-dl to finish.
`[[ $(ps -C youtube-dl -o pid=) ]] || break` - check if there exists a process id for youtube-dl. if exists, loop again. End the loop otherwise.(using `break`).

**NOTE**: `pidof Youtube-dl` command can be used to obtain process ID for a program. however, as youtube-dl is called using python3, it has not process of its own. Thus `pidof youtube-dl` would not yield a value in this case. as such, `ps` command has been used to obtain the pid.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work, it still stalls after running the youtube-dl, can you please explain a bit what you did there? it is quite interesting and it is teaching me a lot.

Comment: `pid="$(Youtube-dl -o output.file link &)";`  # runs Youtube-dl command in background, saving the generated process id in "pid" variable.  `while ([ "${#pid}" -gt 0 ])do sleep 1;done;`  # waits for the process id length to be 0, meaning that there is no process running.  oops! it should be dynamic. hence pid value ought to be updates within the loop. i.e `pid=$(pidof youtube-dl)` . Updating the solution

Comment: This works flawlessly

Answer (score 4):

If you really want only to move the file, why don't output it directly to the destination directory?

```
youtube-dl -o /to-directory/output.file link
```

If you want to perform some other, much complicated task, you could use the option `--exec`, described at the bottom of `youtube-dl -h`, so the command should looks like:

```
youtube-dl -o output.file link --exec 'mv {} /to-directory/'
```

---

Here is а working example:

```
youtube-dl -o irakli https://youtu.be/FyV_49qbvU4 --exec 'mv {} ~/Desktop/'
```

After the command is finished, the file `irakli.mkv` will be at your `Desktop`. Enjoy watching!

---

Bonus track :) Here is one script that I'm using in order to download mp3s from youtube.com, while I'm browsing it via my desktop browser.

```bsh
cat /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl-clipboard # The file must be executable, of course
```

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
notify-send "YouTube-Download BEGIN"
youtube-dl -i -x --audio-format mp3 --output "$HOME/Downloads/%(title)s.%(ext)s" "$(xclip -o)"
```

- Note the script uses `xclip`, so it should be installed, along with the most recent version of [`youtube-dl`](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#how-do-i-update-youtube-dl).

Crate custom shortcut as this:

[image]

Then while you browsing [youtube.com](https://youtube.com), just copy the link of any video you like - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. After few seconds a new mp3 file will be available within the Download directory.

Comment: it says exec command not found, 'youtube-dl -x -o output.file https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N1EhXF1lskA&list=RDN1EhXF1lskA&start_radio=1 --exec 'ffmpeg {} -codec:a libmp3lame -qscale:a 2 output.mp3''

Comment: Hi, @Alessio_110, do we talking about Ubuntu and the most recent version of [`youtube-dl`](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#how-do-i-update-youtube-dl)?

Comment: linux mint 19.2

Comment: Mint is off topic here. However follow the `wget` method from the [link](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#how-do-i-update-youtube-dl), provided above and you will have the newest version of the software with the `--exec` option available. It is strange how an old version could still downloading... @Alessio_110

Comment: I have download it and yet exec is not running. I acknowledge the fact I could just use youtube-dl -x --audio-format mp3 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N1EhXF1lskA&list=RDN1EhXF1lskA&start_radio=1 but I thought I could learn a little bit more today. apologies for wasting everybody's time

Comment: @Alessio_110, I've updated the answer with something that you may like :)

Comment: I was more looking into something without the -exec inbuilt command within youtube-dl however it was quite interesting to know your trick on how to shortcut commands, thanks a bunch!